# Run @bean annotation manually

Tags: java, spring-boot

I work on Spring Boot project. I added localresolver method into a bean. And I want to execute this bean after running the app because I will call a webservice to get the default value of the language.

How can I force this bean to be called after running the app ?

Some people said that we can do it by calling `@postconstruct`.

this is my code :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(LanguageController.getLanguage().get(0));
        return slr;
    }
}
```

the method LanguageController.getLanguage() should not be called before running the app, that's why I would like to execute the bean after.

Comment: yes you can do it using @postcontruct.

Comment: @pvpkiran i have already tested it .. but the bean still executed before running the app !!

Comment: Could you please post your code ?

Comment: @chaoluo I added my code to the question

Comment: When you said *after running the app* it means when the server is initialized or when the user logged in the app?

Comment: @Sigrist .. when the server is initialized

Comment: So where did you put the @ PostConstruct annotation?

Comment: @Sigrist .. I tried to put it on the localeResolver method but it doesn't work.

Comment: You aren't using it right. The `@PostConstruct` is for a Bean, after it has been loaded. You should create a class, autowire the LocaleResolver to it and then create a method with the `@PostConstruct` annotation and them set the default locale

Comment: @Sigrist .. I didn't understand what you have said .. Can you add an answer to this question with an example ? Thx

Comment: this LanguageController you are calling, is it in your own application or some other application?

Comment: @pvpkiran .. actually my project is a maven modular project .. LanguageController is in another module

Comment: @postcontruct is executed as soon the bean in which it is declared is created. But what you need is to execute some piece of code after your web application context is loaded(to call the controller). So i don't think postcontruct wil help. Have a look at ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> or ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>